# MongoDB: What's the debug operation for?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mvc, logback

I am using mongo 3.4 in spring mvc and the version about mongo is

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-mongodb -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

but every 10 seconds there will be debug info showing up:

```
20:10:43.789 DEBUG [cluster-ClusterId{value='58722ad16230c2332cf90a44', description='null'}-139.224.222.20:27017] [o.m.d.cluster]:56 - Checking status of 139.224.222.20:27017
20:10:43.801 DEBUG [cluster-ClusterId{value='58722ad16230c2332cf90a44', description='null'}-139.224.222.20:27017] [o.m.d.cluster]:56 - Updating cluster description to  {type=STANDALONE, servers=[{address=139.224.222.20:27017, type=STANDALONE, roundTripTime=15.2 ms, state=CONNECTED}]
```

Can anybody tell me what's the purpose of the debug operation and will this operation affect the performance?

Answer (score 0):

```
20:10:43.801 DEBUG [cluster-ClusterId{value='58722ad16230c2332cf90a44', description='null'}-139.224.222.20:27017] [o.m.d.cluster]:56 - Updating cluster description to  {type=STANDALONE, servers=[{address=139.224.222.20:27017, type=STANDALONE, roundTripTime=15.2 ms, state=CONNECTED}]
```

the above line does not harm the performance and represents:
//gives the status of the db
       []

There are five severity levels and Debug is one of them and debug has a Verbosity Levels > 0 to determine the amount of Informational and Debug messages MongoDB outputs.

you can set the level of output by this command:

```
db.setLogLevel(-1, "query")
```

-1 if you do not want any debug message otherwise, set level from 1 to 5.